# How to append or combine Ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

Im doing an app with Excel VBA and I need to copy some ranges from different Worksheet in a variable.
All the ranges have the same number of columms but different number of rows. I was thinking on making like a matrix. Just append the UsedRange from every Sheet one down the other... but no way

```
For i = 1 To wbDataFile.Sheets.Count

    Set wsCPDataFile = wbDataFile.Sheets(wbDataFile.Sheets(i).Name)
    If Not DataRng Is Nothing Then
        Set DataRng=  DataRng (Append??)
    Else
    ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
        Set DataRng = wsCPDataFile.UsedRange
    End If

Next I
Data = DataRng
```

Answer (score 11):

Use Union. Like so:

```
Sub jzz()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1")

Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A2"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel vba provided built in method for range combination, which are:

- [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) - *as answered by @Jzz*
- [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)

In case it is required to [duplicate the same range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-multiple-ranges#using-the-range-property), you need to diy, eg refer to  `rng5`:

```
Sub duplicateRange()

    Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 as Range, rng3 as Range, rng4 as Range, rng5 as Range

    Set rng1 = Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = Range("A1")

    Set rng3 = Union(rng1, rng2) ' this will give Range("A1") only

    Set rng4 = Intersect(rng1, rng2) ' this will give Range("A1") only

    Set rng5 = Range(rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address) ' this will give Range("A1,A1")

End Sub
```

Though looks silly, I recently encountered the need to have this duplicated multiple range for plotting purposes. My xValues were referring to the same cell, but at different yValues.